# Student's test for correlation coef

Tags: t-test, pearson-r

In one of the articles I found such a statement:

> The significance of the correlation coefficient was then verified
>   using Student's t test for independent variables

Is this incorrect or did I miss something?

Comment: We'd need some context to understand what the author meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, the author in question was testing for a significant difference of $r$ from 0.  Given $r$ as the Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient, you can then use a $t$ distribution with $N-2$ degrees of freedom for small samples, or a $Z$ distribution for large sample sizes to asses the claim that $r$ is significantly different than 0.  For this, $H_0$ is that $r=0$, and $H_1$ is that $r\ne0$.  Hope that helps a little.

Further reading:

[Correlation Analysis and Regression - York U](http://www.yorku.ca/gisweb/geog2420/lecture18.pdf)

[Correlation - Arizona State](http://www.ltrr.arizona.edu/~dmeko/notes_9.pdf)

[Penn State](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/33)

Answer (score 1):

It is badly worded. Obviously, you can test the significance of the correlation coefficient using a t-test. And the null hypothesis of this test is normally that the correlation coefficient is zero, i.e, the two variables are independent. But it is of course not the t-test for the equality of means with independent variables.